Changing BatchNormalization momentum while training in Keras 3
I'm buidling a custom model using Keras (keras 3.3.3 with python 3.9.19) and I would like to increase the momentum of my BatchNormalization layers during training.
Ideally, I'd like to use a custom model with custom layers rather than a Sequential model and make the most of the "standard" training loop (using fit and Callbacks) rather than using a custom training loop.
I now that there is already a solution using Tensorflow but I'd also like to stick to Keras without relying on any backend functionality (e.g., tf.keras).
Now I know that in Tensorflow, one solution would be to use a tf.Variable in my model, like  self.bn_momentum = tf.Variable(bn_momentum, trainable=False), pass it to my layers, and update it using a Callback during training.
I imagined it would be the same using Keras. However, when trying to use a keras.Variable I get the following error message:
TypeError: Exception encountered when calling CustomClassifier.call().

float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Variable'

So I tried getting rid of the keras.Variable and using a simple float instead. The training seems to go just fine with this, but I suspect that nothing happens under the hood.
I was wondering why keras.Variable does not behave like tf.Variable? and is using a simple float variable a good solution in my case? Thanks in advance for your answers!
Here is a minimal reproductible example:
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras import layers


class CustomClassifier(keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, bn_momentum=0.99, **kwargs):
        
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bn_momentum = bn_momentum # or keras.Variable(bn_momentum, trainable=False)
        self.input_layer = layers.Dense(8, activation="softmax", name="input_layer")
        self.hidden_layer = CustomLayer(16, bn_momentum=self.bn_momentum, name="hidden_layer")      
        self.output_layer = layers.Dense(4, activation="softmax", name="output_scores")

    def call(self, input_points, training=None):
                
        x = self.input_layer(input_points, training=training)
        x = self.hidden_layer(x, training=training)

        return self.output_layer(x)

   
class CustomLayer(layers.Layer):
    
    def __init__(self, units, bn_momentum, **kwargs):
        
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.units = units
        self.bn_momentum = bn_momentum

    def build(self, batch_input_shape):

        self.dense = layers.Dense(self.units, input_shape=batch_input_shape)
        self.bn = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=self.bn_momentum)
        self.activation = layers.ReLU()

    def call(self, x, training=None):

        x = self.dense(x)
        x = self.bn(x, training=training)

        return self.activation(x)


class BatchNormalizationMomentumScheduler(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    """The decay rate for batch normalization starts with 0.5 and is gradually 
    increased to 0.99."""

    def __init__(self,):
        super().__init__()

        self.initial_momentum = 0.5
        self.final_momentum = 0.99
        self.rate = 0.05

    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):

        self.model.bn_momentum = self.initial_momentum
        print(f"Initial BatchNormalization momentum is {self.model.bn_momentum:.3f}.")

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):

        if epoch:
            new_bn_momentum = self.initial_momentum + self.rate * epoch
            new_bn_momentum = np.min([new_bn_momentum, self.final_momentum])
            self.model.bn_momentum = new_bn_momentum
            print(f"Epoch {epoch}: BatchNormalization momentum is {self.model.bn_momentum:.3f}.")
            

if __name__ =="__main__":

    # Generate random data
    X = np.random.random((1024, 8))
    y = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3], 1024)

    # Instanciate and train model
    model = CustomClassifier()
    model.build((64, 8))
    model.summary()
    model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam")
    history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, callbacks=[BatchNormalizationMomentumScheduler()])

    # Check final
    print("Model momentum after training:", model.bn_momentum)


